# i want to know about the query if succeded or fail

Tags: prolog

Consider the following program.

```
a(X):-
     b(X), c(X), d(X).
a(X):-
     c(X), d(X).
a(X):-
     d(X).

b(1).                             
b(a).                            
b(2).
b(3).

d(10).
d(11).

c(3).
c(4).
```

Given the query ?- a(X). Indicate in the box below the successive variable bindings that the variable X gets when the above query is run, and all solutions are asked for (by using ;). NB you should list even those bindings which do not lead to overall success, and you should list each answer even if it occurs more than once

Answer (score 0):

The query succeeds with
X = 10
X = 11

Comment: *NB you should list even those bindings which do not lead to overall success*